# how to use both Ontouch and Onclick for an ImageButton?

Tags: android

in my app,  i want two things to happen.

1. when i touch and drag the ImageButton, it should move along with my finger.

   i used `OnTouchListener()` for this and it works fine.
2. when i click the ImageButton, it should close the activity.

   i used `OnClickListener()` for this and it also works fine.

So, here is my problem. whenever i move the `ImageButton` `OnTouchListener` is tirggered and the `ImageButton` moves, the `OnClickListener` is also triggered at the end when i am releasing the button from moving.

How to use ontouch and onclick listeners on the same button without interfering on each other?

Comment: use gesturedetector to detect singletap

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Hi, can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452949/android-working-with-ontouch-onclick-and-onlongclick-together.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try this, It may help you

No need to set `onClick()` method `onTouch()` will handle both the case.

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img);

        imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1)) {
                    // single tap
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // your code for move and drag
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In my case, I had to use onSingleTapUp() rather than onSingleTapConfirmed(), but other than that, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: onSingleTapConfirmed() does not work and onSingleTapUp() is not suitable for this.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh

SingleTapConfirm class should override onDown method - it should return true, because when false is returned rest of gestures are ignored

Comment: Why u used  `return true` in class SingleTapConfirm() ? I made it `false` still it was working .

Comment: Should gesture detector be so sensitive? Is there a way to adjust what is a tap (in ms) and what not?

Comment: @JyotmanSingh by returning true for `onDown` method, the touch even triggers that onDown and there is no distinction between touch and click then. Can you guide me?

Comment: is it possible to combine onClick onTouch and onLongClick?

Comment: I have found a error in this. single click is detected each time on when we double tap.

Answer (score 36):

To have `Click Listener`, `DoubleClick Listener`, `OnLongPress Listener`, `Swipe Left`, `Swipe Right`, `Swipe Up`, `Swipe Down` on Single `View` you need to `setOnTouchListener`. i.e,

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                super.onClick();
                // your on click here
            }

            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick() {
                super.onDoubleClick();
                // your on onDoubleClick here
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick() {
                super.onLongClick();
                // your on onLongClick here
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeUp() {
                super.onSwipeUp();
                // your swipe up here
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeDown() {
                super.onSwipeDown();
                // your swipe down here.
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                super.onSwipeLeft();
                // your swipe left here.
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                super.onSwipeRight();
                // your swipe right here.
            }
        });

}
```

For this you need `OnSwipeTouchListener` class that implements `OnTouchListener`.

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context c) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureListener());
}

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        onClick();
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        onDoubleClick();
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        onLongClick();
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    // Determines the fling velocity and then fires the appropriate swipe event accordingly
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeDown();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeUp();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeUp() {
}

public void onSwipeDown() {
}

public void onClick() {

}

public void onDoubleClick() {

}

public void onLongClick() {

}
}
```

Comment: Not use full. Double-tap detects single tap each time and the double-tap.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with onClick and OnTouch event is that the moment you Click(with the intention to Click) it assumes the event to be OnTouch thus OnClick is never interpreted. The work around

```
isMove = false;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//Your stuff
isMove = false;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
if (!isMove || (Xdiff < 10 && Ydiff < 10 ) {
view.performClick; //The check for Xdiff <10 && YDiff< 10 because sometime elements moves a little
even when you just click it   
}
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
isMove = true;
```

Comment: Xdiff would be difference between new x coordinate and the previous x coordination. So at each step you save the prev position.That is ontouch xprev is computed and on action up xnew (current x) is computed. xdiff = xcurrent - xprev. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Or you could set `isMove = true` in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` only if the difference is greater than 10

Answer (score 6):

I've tried to apply @Biraj solution in my project and it didn't work - I've noticed that extension of `SimpleOnGestureListener` should not only override `onSingleTapConfirmed` method, but `onDown` as well. Due to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html):

> If you return false from onDown(), as GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener does by default, the system assumes that you want to ignore the rest of the gesture, and the other methods of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener never get called

Below is complex solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img);

        imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1)) {
                    // single tap
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // your code for move and drag
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            /*it needs to return true if we don't want 
            to ignore rest of the gestures*/
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I suppose, that this behaviour can be caused by difference GestureDetectorCompat, but I'll follow [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) and I'm going to use second one:

> You should use Support Library classes where possible to provide compatibility with devices running Android 1.6 and higher

Comment: This would return true for scroll events too, since onDown() returns true.

Comment: @Krzysztof has the right idea; I managed to avoid the Type 1 error by using two listeners, one with both the Tap Up I'm looking for and the onDown, and the other with just the onDown; in my gridTouched handler, I begin with
`
    // only want tap ups
    if(!singleTapUpDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) return false;
    // don't want onDown
    if(downCatchDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) return true;
`

Comment: I do want onLongPress too,is there any way i can get it too?

Answer (score 6):

**In `MainActivity` code this.**

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener_imp extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_swipe_touch_listener);

    ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.view);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(OnSwipeTouchListener_imp.this)
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick()
        {
            super.onClick(); // your on click here              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick()
        {
            super.onDoubleClick(); // your on onDoubleClick here               
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick()
        {
            super.onLongClick(); // your on onLongClick here                
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeUp() {
            super.onSwipeUp(); // your swipe up here                
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeDown() {
            super.onSwipeDown();  // your swipe down here.

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            super.onSwipeLeft(); // your swipe left here.                
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onSwipeLeft",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight(); // your swipe right here.                
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onSwipeRight",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Then create a `OnSwipeTouchListener` java Class.**

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context c) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureListener());
}

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        onClick();
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        onDoubleClick();
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        onLongClick();
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    // Determines the fling velocity and then fires the appropriate swipe event accordingly
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    if (diffX > 0)
                    {
                        onSwipeRight(); // Right swipe
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();  // Left swipe
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeDown(); // Down swipe
                    } else {
                        onSwipeUp(); // Up swipe
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeUp() {
}

public void onSwipeDown() {
}

public void onClick() {
}

public void onDoubleClick() {
}

public void onLongClick() {
}
}
```

Hope this lights u:)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can work with a boolean.

lets say 
    Boolean isMoving = false;

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 isMoving = true;

          // implement your move codes
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               isMoving = false;
    break;

default:
        break;
    }
```

and then in your onclick method check for the boolean. If it is false, then perform the click action, if true ... do not act.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    switch (arg0.getId()) {

    case R.id.imagebutton:
        if(!isMoving) {
                   //code for on click here
                }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm not too late but you can achieve this by time counter.
A click takes less than a second so with that in mind....

```
    long prev=0;
    long current = 0;
    long dif =0; 
   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    prev = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    current = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                    dif = current - prev;
                    if (dif == 0) {
                        //Perform Your Click Action
                    }
                    break;
                 }
           }
```

Hope it helps out someone

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate between touch, click and swipe by getting the difference in the x,y values like:

```
var prevY = 0
var prevX = 0
    controls.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->

                when (event?.actionMasked) {

                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        prevY = event.rawY.toInt()
                        prevX = event.rawX.toInt()

                    }

                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP->{
                        Log.d("Controls","Action up")
                        var y = event.rawY.toInt()
                        var x = event.rawX.toInt()
                        val diffY = Math.abs(prevY - y)
                        val diffX = Math.abs(prevX - x)
                        if(diffX in 0..10 && diffY in 0..10){
                          // its a touch
                        }
                         //check diffY if negative, is a swipe down, else swipe up
                      //check diffX if negative, its a swipe right, else swipe left
                    }
                }
                true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clieck Listener event; if actiondown and action up in your components bounds than call onclicklistener. Thus onclick event activate with touch detection. You could only set onTouchListener and receive click events if action up and action down in your components start position.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a private variable like: `boolean hasMoved = false;`

When the image button begins to move, set `hasMoved = true`

In your `OnClickListener` execute code only `if(!hasMoved)` -- meaning perform on click functionality only if the button has not moved. Set `hasMoved = false;` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a boolean field and set it to true value when your OnTouchListener is triggered. after that when the OnClickListener wants to trigger you will check the boolean field and if true don't act anything in your  onClickListener.

```
    private blnTouch = false;

private OnTouchListener btnOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        blnOnTouch = true;
    }
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        blnOnTouch = false;
    }
               }
 };

private OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (blnOnTouch){
            // Do Your OnClickJob Here without touch and move
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: onTouch will be triggered everytime, so basically onclick will never be called under your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Perfect example for Both touch n tap both    
private void touchNtap() {
            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(itemView.getContext()
                    , new SingleTapConfirm());


            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                        // program for click events
                        gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed() returned: " + true);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTap() returned: " + true);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent() returned: " + true);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }else {
                        //program for touch events
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
Create a Inner class 

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```