# How a move-able button when pressed performs something

Tags: android, eclipse

I wrote all the code for a button which is move-able or drag-able with a finger press, now i  also want that button to perform something when it is clicked (for example go to a website when clicked in my case)
 I implemented all the code in a separate class like this:

```
public class MultiTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{





private float mPrevX;
private float mPrevY;

public MainActivity mainActivity;
public MultiTouchListener(MainActivity mainActivity1) {
    mainActivity = mainActivity1;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    float currX,currY;
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {




            mPrevX = event.getX();
            mPrevY = event.getY();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {

                currX = event.getRawX();
                currY = event.getRawY();


                MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());   
                marginParams.setMargins((int)(currX - mPrevX), (int)(currY - mPrevY),0, 0);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 


            break;
        }



        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
    }

    return true;
}



}
```

and i call it in my main activity by this

```
  MultiTouchListener touchListener=new MultiTouchListener(this);
                onButton.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Moveable drag and drop button is working fine, i just want this button to Open a website link when pressed, What changes do i have to make in my code to perform this.Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Under `ACTION_UP` in your onTouchListener, you have to manually call `view.performClick()`. This will trigger your onclick listener, which you can then use to open your web page.

So something like this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    view.performClick();
    break;
```

and then

```
    onButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

Hmm. So apparently doing that will drown out the drag and drop aspect of it. Try this instead (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton) and modified somewhat for your class).

In your ontouch class:

```
//create a gesturedetector
private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
//...etc
switch (action ) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(view)) {
                // this is a "click", put your click event here
                return true;
    } else {
           //your original touch drag and drop code should go here
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
           //...
           }

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           {
            //...
           break;
           }
           //etc
    }

}

    return false;
}


private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

With this, you shouldn't need an onclick listener anymore. See if that works.

Comment: Showing an error on onButton.setOnClickListener and also cant even start another activity it says startactivity not defined for ontouchlistener

Comment: Where are you defining your onclick listener? It should be in your main activity, not the ontouchlistener.

Comment: as i mentioned  i have made a different class.

Comment: `and i call it in my main activity by this` <-- from your post. So I presume you're setting your ontouchlistener in your MainActivity. Just stick the onclick listener under it.

Comment: Did the same at first but it doesnt really work, it takes me to the website but the button is no more dragable than