# onTouchListener only works when pressed for second time

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a method that acts as a `ColorStateList`or Selector when a View is pressed. When a view is passed into the method `onClickColorSelector`
it takes the view and sets a `setOnTouchListener`, so when the user press down on a `view`, the view gets a selector effect.

**Now the problem** is that `onTouchListener` is only called when a View is clicked for the second time. Why does it behave like that and how to solve it?

***Note!*** Dont suggest me ColorStateList!

*onClickColorSelector is in a class called ViewSelector*

```
  public void onClickColorSelector(View view, final int onPressColor) {

    Log.d("TAG" , "1");
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        int defaultTextColor = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("TAG" , "2");
                if (view instanceof TextView) {
                    Log.d("TAG" , "3");
                    defaultTextColor = ((TextView) view).getCurrentTextColor();
                    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(onPressColor);
                }
                Log.d("TAG" , "4");
                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                return true;

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (view instanceof TextView) {

                    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(defaultTextColor);
                }

                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);


                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This is how `onClickColorSelector();` is called from a another class:

```
ViewSelector vs = new ViewSelector(this);

      loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            vs.onClickColorSelector(loginBtn, Color.RED);


        }
    });
```

Comment: call this `vs.onClickColorSelector(loginBtn, Color.RED);` in your `OnCreate()` method ......

Comment: @sushildlh Its was the answer! Haha its so funny when such a small thing is missed! write it as an answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's Activated on when you press the button ...
>
> That is the reason it running 2nd time ....
>
> So call this `vs.onClickColorSelector(loginBtn, Color.RED);` in your
>   `OnCreate()` method

Comment: Any suggestion of why this code makes view.OnClick to not work anymore?

Comment: I think you already have OnTouch listener on the button .... have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19539206/5305430

Comment: I solved it by setting `view.callOnClick();` inside if this call  `(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {}`