# OnClickListener is not working as wanted

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have this code, and the problem is in the `OnClickListener`.
I don't usually use onClickListener, but because there is no activity to set the property onClick.

It triggers when i release my finger even after i hold on it for a while, so it's not felling like a click, it's like when you make `OnTouchListener` and the case : `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

I need it to trigger only when you make a fast simply touch on it.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class Bubble extends Service{
private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView chatHead;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.DISPLAY_CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.DISPLAY_CLIP_VERTICAL| Gravity.START;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
    params.alpha = 0.5f;
    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

    chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(Bubble.this, MainActivity.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }
    });

    try{
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return false;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead , paramsF);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }catch(Exception ignored){}
}
```

Comment: Touch takes control over click. You can try to return true in a certain case, though

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, but then the clickListener will not work too.

Comment: You can move your click listener logics into `ACTION_UP` case.

Comment: @azizbekian unfortunately, did't work.

Comment: remove the flag   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 that worked for me, i'm gonna post an answer for it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use both Ontouch and Onclick for an ImageButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GestureDetector to detect if it's a single tap, and that worked perfectly.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Bubble extends Service{
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new     WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.DISPLAY_CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.DISPLAY_CLIP_VERTICAL| Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        params.alpha = 0.5f;
        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

        try{
            chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(Bubble.this, MainActivity.class);
                        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(dialogIntent);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        switch (event.getAction()){
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                initialX = paramsF.x;
                                initialY = paramsF.y;
                                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                return false;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                                paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead , paramsF);
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception ignored){}
    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```