# using both onTouch and onClick on a button in android

Tags: android, onclick, ontouch

I have a `Button` that whenever the user clicks it, it increases the number in my `EditText`, but i want to have an onTouch method that when the user keeps their finger on the button the number increases with more speed(continuously), something like the backspace, that when you click it, it deleted just one letter and when you keep it down, it deletes the words faster, so i have both ontouch and onclick in my code, but whenever i click the button only onTouch triggers, what should i do? can anybody help, please? I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything that helps me

**Here is part of my code**

```
     btnFineUp.setOnTouchListener (this);   
            btnFineUp.setOnClickListener (this);

    @override
            public void onClick (View view)
        {
            switch (view.getId ())
            {
                case R.id.btn_fine_up:

                {
                    View     v = findViewById (getCurrentFocus ().getId ());
                    EditText editText;

                    if (v instanceof EditText)
                    {
                        editText = (EditText) v;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    int calcStateAmp   = +1;

                     if (view.getId () == R.id.btn_fine_up)
                    {
                        calcState_2 = upAndDown.getFineUpAmp () * calcStateAmp;

                        calcStateAmp = calcState_2;

                    }
                    double currentValue;
                    if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty (editText.getText ().toString ()))
                    {
                        currentValue = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentValue = Double.parseDouble (editText.getText ().toString ());
                    }
                    switch (getCurrentFocus ().getId ())
                    {
                        case R.id.txt_va1_a:
                        case R.id.txt_va2_a:
                        case R.id.txt_va3_a:
                        case R.id.txt_vb1_a:

                            editText.setText (String.format (Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", currentValue + (0.01 * calcStateAmp)));
                            break;
    }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch (View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
                switch (view.getId ())
                {
                    case ir.vebko.R.id.btn_fine_up:

                    {
                        View     v = findViewById (getCurrentFocus ().getId ());
                        EditText editText;

                        if (v instanceof EditText)
                        {
                            editText = (EditText) v;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        int calcStateAmp   = +1;



             if (view.getId () == R.id.btn_fine_up)
                        {
                            calcStateAmp = calcState_2;

                        }
                        double currentValue;
                        if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty (editText.getText ().toString ()))
                        {
                            currentValue = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentValue = Double.parseDouble (editText.getText ().toString ());
                        }

                        switch (getCurrentFocus ().getId ())
                        {
                            case ir.vebko.R.id.txt_va1_a:
                            case ir.vebko.R.id.txt_va2_a:
                            case ir.vebko.R.id.txt_va3_a:
                            case ir.vebko.R.id.txt_vb1_a:

                                editText.setText (String.format (Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", currentValue + (0.01 * calcStateAmp)));
                                break;
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Return `false` may be it will help you [Use both onTouch and onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0):

[`OnTouch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent)) itself handles the click user action for [`OnClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View)) as well. Thus, a click user action raises an `OnTouch` event first; only when there is no listener listening to `OnTouch` does it invoke the `OnClick` event. Since you have an `OnTouchListener` associated with the `OnTouch` event, there is no way your `OnClickListener` will be invoked.  For more details, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton).

From your question, it seems that you can skip `View.OnTouchListener` altogether and instead implement both [`View.OnLongClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick(android.view.View)) and `View.OnClickListener`.

Hope that helps.