# Webview click event not working while using setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, webview

I am using `webview` to display HTML file. In webview add swipe left and right.
I am using below class to swipe functionality.

```
/**
 * Detects left and right swipes across a view.
 */
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                    onSwipeRight();
                else
                    onSwipeLeft();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

copy from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures).

My code is:

```
    webview.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            super.onSwipeLeft();
            onNextClick();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight();
            onPrevClick();
        }

    });
```

Working fine in swipe left and swipe right.

My problem is:

**Webview internal click not working.**

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton ??

Comment: @PankajKumar I already added gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) in OnTouch event.

Comment: you are always returning `true` in `onDown`, which likely means that you have consumed the finger down event, and it won't be passed onward in the system, which means that click event will never happen, as a click is touch down + touch up.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko If I return false or super.onDown(e) in onDown then webview not loaded