# Using both setOnTouchListener and setOnClickListener on a button

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function that shrinks the size of a view on `ACTION_DOWN`, and returns it to original size on `ACTION_UP`. This function is strictly for aesthetics. I have setOnClickListeners on the buttons so they can (in theory...) execute code when the button is pressed.

```
private fun scaleButton(theButton:View, grow:Boolean){
    theButton.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.isPressed = true

            if (grow) {
                v.animate().scaleX(1.04F).scaleY(1.04F).setDuration(50)
            } else {
                v.animate().scaleX(0.97F).scaleY(0.97F).setDuration(50)
            }

        } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            v.isPressed = false
            v.animate().scaleX(1.0F).scaleY(1.0F).setDuration(100)
        }
        false
    })
}
```

**The problem is `setOnClickListener` is never called.**

onCreate:

```
scaleButton(button1,false)
scaleButton(button2,true)
scaleButton(button3,false)

button1.setOnClickListener {
    println("Button 1 Pressed")
}
button2.setOnClickListener {
    println("Button 2 Pressed")
}
button3.setOnClickListener {
    println("Button 3 Pressed")
}
```

**How can I both scale the button via animation (on touch) AND trigger `setOnClickListener`**

Comment: did you try to return 'false' in 'OnTouchListener'?

Comment: Yes. That didn't change anything. I edited the code in my original post.

Comment: Ok I googled a little bit. May be this one will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your click listener will never fire because the touch listener is supposed to tell the system when the elemnt was clicked.  Yours isn't.  Either add a performClick at the appropriate time, or put everything into the touch listener and perform the click on action_up

Comment: Thanks Gabe. Adding performClick() at the end of ACTION_UP did the trick.

Comment: That's the better solution anyway. I just remembered the other reason to do that- without it accessibility features won't work on that view