# How to avoid ontouchlistner to stop working when clicked on imageview

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

In my application, i have set `OnTouchListener` and `OnClickListener` to an `ImageView`.
Problem is when i click an `ImageView` both `OnTouchListener` and `OnClickListener` are working. But i want to avoid the `OnTouchListener` when clicked on image, and when dragging the ImageView `OnTouchListener` should work and `OnClickListener` should be avoided.
Any suggestions...

Below is my code:

```
imageview.setOnClickListener(m_onClickListner);
imageview.setOnTouchListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

    }
    return true;
}

OnClickListener m_onClickListner = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: see my edit, code is also posted...

Comment: you may use Button.setEnabled(false); for not clicking

Comment: This is already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480418/receiving-ontouch-and-onclick-events-with-android

Comment: there no answer in that link and also if i use only on touch every time it is calling MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN...but in that i am creating new imageview for dragging, so for click of an event also it is creating new image.. i don't want to use action_down when clicking of an imageview

Answer (score 0):

i that case you should use setOnLongClickListener for dragging.

```
imageview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: how to calculate the x,y positions of the view using onlongclick, i am using 2.2 api and i am calculating the x,y positions using ontouch motionevent...

Comment: yes that's right you cant get MotionEvent on it. is there just ImageView or list are you useing ?